# Is it possible to have 2 random variables with the same distribution have different means.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I know that $E[X]=\int X dp$. If $X'$ is a independent copy of $X$. is it necessary that $E[X]=E[X']$?
I cant seem to come up with a proof.

Comment: The expected value of a random variable is completely determined by the distribution of the r.v., therefore an idential distribution implies an identical expected value.

Answer (score 1):

No.

$E(X) = \int x f_X(x) dx$
Nothing in that expression changes if you have the same distribution.  Expected value of the variable is a property of a distribution.